# Admin is returning a 404 on styles.css and theme.js on Magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, admin, css, less, 404

The backend of my `Magento` installation is not loading `CSS/JS`. I have reached a point where I just cannot work out why this is happening and hoping that someone might have an idea.

This is what I am seeing:

[image]

I can also see that in `pub/static/adminhtml/backend/en_US` there is no `css` folder.

This is what I have tried to resolve this:

- Confirmed .htaccess is present in the pub/static folder
- In developer mode, I have ran the following commands:

```
bin/magento cache:clean
bin/magento cache:flush     
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

- Set `dev/static/sign` to 0 directly in DB.
- Built in production mode with:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

- Checked and reset all permissions
- Checked `var/log/` for any indications of errors - there is just this:

```
main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/css/styles.css' [] []
main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/css/styles.css' [] []
main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/js/theme.js' [] []
main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/js/theme.js' [] []
```

I have spent way too long searching for an answer on here, Google, etc. and it just seems to send me in circles with all suggestions being one of the above.

I am guessing it might be something simple, something I have overlooked but I am just not seeing it today. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Delete all folder in pub/static/ expect .htaccess.
Run command: php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
Good luck.

Comment: @RanjeetKumar Yes, as I said, I have tried that. Running setup:upgrade empties that folder anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So my issue seems to have been fixed now by completely removing the `vendor` folder and running:

```
composer install
```

I have no idea why this fixed the issue, I have never changed anything in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to run below commands

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* generated/*
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

After running above command please try to refresh your Backend. Make sure that URL Rewrite also enabled.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Yes I have ran all of those commands in that order more than once and same issue. Forgot to mention above, checking rewrite was enabled was one of the first things I tried.

Comment: Still you're not able to open backend ?

Comment: Nope. CSS is not being generated.
Also, 777 on pub directory is an incredibly bad idea!

Comment: Can you please press **CTRL + U** in your browser and then check what is your locale there ?

Comment: Yeah thats en-US

Comment: Did you set default Magento file and directory permission there ?

Comment: Yep. All permissions are fine.